# Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x12

Tags: spl-token, spl-associated-token-account

I am getting this error when trying to do an SPL token transfer.

[Solana Docs](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/error.rs) makes it seem as if this is a 'Frozen Account' error. I am not sure why the account of the sender or the newly created account of the receiver is 'Frozen'

My code can be found [here](https://github.com/Melbourneandrew/TokenBuddy/blob/master/src/methods/web3SendSPL.js)

Answer (score 1):

`0x12` in hex is 18 in decimal. So I think the error you're seeing is:

```
/// Mint decimals mismatch between the client and mint
#[error("The provided decimals value different from the Mint decimals")]
MintDecimalsMismatch,
```

Your code doesn't include the public keys so I can't confirm, but I think you'll probably find that the mint doesn't have 2 decimals. So I think the error is here in your code:

```
  const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    createTransferCheckedInstruction(
      senderTokenAccount.address,
      mintPk,
      recieverTokenAccount.address,
      sender.publicKey,
      tokenAmmount,
      2 // decimals of mint, this is checked and I think is incorrect
    )
```